# Can I use the word "GO" as synonym to "Party"?

Tags: vocabulary

Is it okay to say "Work go" as a synonym to party? Or say Hen go/Stag go instead of Hen do/Stag do?

Comment: I've heard "work do", but not "work go". I've never heard hen or stag go, normally hens' night or stag night.

Comment: Thank you! But also the question is more about "Can I?" say so and if that would be understandable, and is the word GO used as a synonym to "party"

Comment: This is a strange question.  It is like "can I use the word 'chicken' to mean 'purple'"  The answer is "No,  why would you think that?"

Comment: No, **go** does not mean **party**.

Comment: You can "throw a party"  or "have a do" which is BrEng but "go"? where did you see this? Explain why you think that "hen go" is synonymous with a "bash" or a "get together"? It's sometimes called a **hen do** in British English, sometimes it's a **hen night** but I think the Americans call it a **bachelorette party**

Answer (score 3):

In the UK, 'do' is synonymous to 'party'.
'Go' is not.

To find it in any dictionary, you will have to scroll well down the page. - eg  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do

> do *noun* [C] (PARTY)
> <sup>mainly UK informal</sup>
> a party or other social event:
> *Colin's having a bit of a do for his 50th birthday.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a word any way you like; and, with suitable context, people may even understand what you mean. (If I say "See that red ksplut over there?", and point to a red car, most people will understand what I mean).

But if nobody else uses the word that way, you might strike people as a bit odd.

I am not aware of "go" used for "party". Such a sense is not listed in the OED or Wiktionary.